# English equivalent of 'стерпится - слюбится'?

Tags: proverbs, russian

Are there any proverbs in the English-speaking world that are close in their meaning to the Russian proverb "*стерпится - слюбится*"?

Meaning of the proverb: if you do something unpleasant at first for a long enough period of time, you will actually end up liking it.

Comment: Sort of the opposite: 'familiarity breeds contempt'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no corresponding idiom in English, so popular and so synthetic. The meaning is: "стерпится, слюбится" =

"*frequenting is liking*", "you will like it(/her/him) when you get used to it". There are some sayings that convey roughly the same meaning, anyway:

- do it first and you'll like it later;
- liking comes of habit.

and referring to marriage:

- marry first, and love will come afterwards;
- marry first, and love will follow;
- age/winter and wedlock tames man and beast;
- a love comes with habit.

Comment: I like "_liking comes of habit_" and your translatiion of the proverb as "_frequenting is liking_" :)

Comment: @user132181, Yes, if it were a set phrase, known to the general public, like "*seeing is believing*",  it would be the perfect translation.

Comment: [*Liking comes of habit*](https://www.google.it/search?q=liking+comes+of+habit&oq=liking+comes+of+habit&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22liking+comes+of+habit%22)  is NOT a typical English idiom or saying. On Google it only has 14 results. And [*do it first and you'll like it later*](https://www.google.it/search?q=liking+comes+of+habit&oq=liking+comes+of+habit&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22do+it+first+and+you%27ll+like+it+later%22) has only four results!

Comment: And your last variant [*a love comes with habit*](https://www.google.it/search?q=liking+comes+of+habit&oq=liking+comes+of+habit&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22a+love+comes+with+habit%22&start=10) garners only 11 results.

Comment: Finally, [*frequenting is liking*](https://www.google.it/search?q=frequenting+is+liking&oq=frequenting+is+liking&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22frequenting+is+liking%22) is not an English expression, and no native speaker would utter this expression. In fact on the Internet there is but one result, and it is this post.

Comment: Mark, @Mari-LouA's comments aer basically telling the OP that, though each one of your examples may very well be good translations of the Russian concept, they are in no way proverbs/idioms in English.

Comment: Mark, it's good to be explicit. I wasn't aware of these phrases before, and thought that maybe some people use them, but @Mari-LouA did actual research, confirming my doubts. If the OP already knew any of this, why would they ask?

Comment: @Mitch, OP knew before posting that no idiom exists, he was looking for a translation (as close as possible) that conveyed that idea. The ones I quoted are not in use, my translation is the nearest thing, even if it is not a set phrase at all, as I admitted. Thanks for your vote, anyway, someone else blindly downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

An "*acquired taste*" conveys a similar meaning. Although it's most often used in the context of food and drink, it would be understood in other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

The following in bold type are idiomatic sayings that convey the sense of adapting to change over time and how that might, initially, be a struggle, but with perseverance and patience one may begin to even like the new situation.

> - You don't really get to choose, but you can **grow to love**<sup>[1](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=grow%20to%20love&l=0)</sup> someone over time.
> - For me, growing up in southeast London, it's so inconceivable that in my life I'd play this man and **grow to love** him.
> - For starters, it took me a while to **get used to the idea** <sup>[2](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=get%20used%20to%20the%20idea&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=)</sup> of a computerized test
> - People **get used to the idea** of doing something that yesterday was considered impossible.
> - I'm happy to report Marcus is **adjusting** well **to life** <sup>[3](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?hardm=1&t=0&l=0&p=1&q=adjusting%20to%20life)</sup> as a college freshman.
> - Even for the most independent and sociable teenagers, **adjusting to college life** is tricky.
> - These hot Mexican dishes seem impossible at first. They **take some getting used to**, I agree. But it's worth it.
> - It **takes some getting used to** <sup>[4](http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=getting%20used%20to&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=)</sup>, but this color scheme is much easier on your eyes

Answer (score 0):

How about **[Fake it till you make it](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_it_till_you_make_it)**?

Essentially, pretend to be something until you are.